# Can we create Email Inbox in WPF application

Tags: wpf

In my WPF project i have a mailbox option. Where user can only send emails from his EmailID. Now i want to implement Email Inbox in my application,where user can see Emails of his EmailAccount(Yahoo,Gmail..etc).
Is this gonna work..
Please Help me.
Thanks advance.

Answer (score 0):

It can, you need to explore the API available for invoking mails of user from Yahoo and Gmail. Sometimes api are not exposed in that case u need to use http post methods, http web request and then get the result and show user emails.

I suggest to search if some api available for retrieving mails from user inbox